# Base64 - Embedded image drag-and-drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, base64

I embedded an base64 image like this:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" title="My image" alt=""My image" src="data:image/png;base64,AUa4GWAoUW...
```

If I drag-and-drop that image from the browser to my desktop I just get a HTML document shown instead of a PNG image. (Firefox / Opera)

How to make drag and drop for base64 images possible?

Thanks

Comment: Easy, just fix your browser's source code and recompile!

Comment: While this is a terribly inefficient approach, you might try using jQuery to place the image into another image to defeat the browsers issue.  Then overlay it on top of the original image.